# I am trying to build a simple program to read information from a mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode

I want to write a command-line tool that will allow me to enter in commands and a variable and then the tool will return information sourced from a SQL database

I have created a project in Xcode, Installed mysql-connector-c++ and boost using homebrew but whenever I try to include the headers it will not allow me to compile, I have even tried using the exact path

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h"
#include "/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/include/jdbc/mysql_driver.h"
#include "/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/include/jdbc/mysql_error.h"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

a simple program i suggest using php ; i'm not sure about c++ but the language could be similar ;

save a example.php file :

```
<?php

error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taiwan');

// include files for required variables ;

$mysqli = new mysqli($Host, $User, $Password, $CustomerDB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$arrayReceive = array();

if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

$sql = "select * from $DB.customeritem where Status='ACTIVE'";

$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$res){echo "Failed query Line18customeritem: (".$mysqli->errno.") ". $mysqli->error;}

echo "No. of customeritems : ".$res->num_rows."\r\n";

while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
    // code to handle each row return from mysql query ;
}//end while

$_SESSION["customeritemArray"] = $customeritemArray;

// $mysqli->close();

?>
```

then command-line tool can enter :
php -f C:\wamp64\www\projectFolder\example.php

or you could make it a script.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen in the mysql connector docs that the includes goes right that:

```
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/*.h>
```

Look that there are no **""** it is **<>**

Comment: I have tried this directly however I get an error, Here is the error https://imgur.com/a/YVPm5uc